# installing ohmyzsh claims zsh not installed

Tags: homebrew, zsh

I have installed zsh with homebrew, and am now trying to install oh-my-zsh.

```
% brew install zsh
...

Warning: zsh-5.3.1 already installed
```

That installs zsh, and sets my `$SHELL` variable to `/usr/local/bin/zsh`

```
% which zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
% echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/zsh
```

But when I try and install oh-my-zsh from the github source, I'm told that zsh has not been installed.

```
% curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | sh
Zsh is not installed! Please install zsh first!
```

Looking at the install script, it appears that zsh has not been added to my `etc/scripts` file.

```
% grep zsh /etc/shells | wc
0 0 0
```

Why is homebrew not "correctly" installing zsh? How can I update my `/etc/shells` file to include the necessary information?

Comment: Most of this question doesn't make sense. `/bin/zsh` is pre-installed on Mac OS X and appears in `/etc/shells`. Further, simply installing something via `brew` isn't going to modify your login shell. (And looking for an entry in `/etc/shells` would just tell you if a shell is allowed as a login shell, not if it is installed on a system at all.)

Comment: Can you show us the entire content of `/etc/shells`?

Comment: FYI if you want to use homebrew's zsh as login shell, you have to edit `/etc/shells` to add `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

Comment: @chepner I included the installation via brew because the installation instructions for oh-my-zsh recommend installing a non-system version, and I wasn't sure if the installation with brew was causing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

After looking at the contents of my /etc/shells file, it appeared that something had damaged that file. Very strange.

Rewriting the /etc/shells to the following fixed the issue for me.

```
/usr/local/bin/zsh
/bin/bash
```

Then I can change shells as I would expect and installing oh-my-zsh works.